# How to not catch a particular line exception in try catch box in JAVA?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Here is my code:

```
whatever exception it throws I don't want to catch it outside, I want to continue my loop again by handling it separately. I don't want to use another try catch inside this try catch. Can someone guide me on this?
```

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use another try/catch? That's the obvious way of doing it.

Comment: Not particularly pleasantly, no. (I would potentially extract a submethod to make the whole thing cleaner, but...) If your senior has added a requirement not to use the most obvious approach to do something, you should ask them how they *do* want you to handle this.

Comment: this is bcz try catch inside try catch is not good in practice, we can use 2 try catches but not nested, he said.

Comment: Well we don't know which of the calls you're making can throw which of the exceptions. But it sounds like you *do* want a nested try/catch and a vague "not good practice" is no substitute for "code that works". See whether your senior would be happy with the second one being in another method that you call from the first... and if he still says no, then get *him* to show you what he'd do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to use another try catch inside this try catch.

Yes you do.

```
 MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject = new MarketplaceBO(entity.getMarketplaceID());
 try {
    marketplaceBOObject.loadFromSable();
 } catch (WhateverException e) {
    // Do something here, or, if you prefer, add the exception to a list and process later
    doSomething() ;
    // Continue your loop above
    continue ;
 }
 if (marketplaceBOObject.isActive()) {
```

If you REALLY don't want to do this, your loadFromSable() method could return some object that provides information about success/failure of the call.  But I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

do this way -- this way your rest of the code will run no matter there is an exception or not

```
        for (MerchantMarketplaceBO entity : merchantMarketplaceBOList) {
            MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject = new MarketplaceBO(entity.getMarketplaceID());

            try{
                marketplaceBOObject.loadFromSable();
                if (marketplaceBOObject.isActive()) {
                    resultVector.add(marketplaceBOObject.getCodigoMarketplace());
                }

            }
            catch{
                if (marketplaceBOObject.isActive()) {
                    resultVector.add(marketplaceBOObject.getCodigoMarketplace());
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This won't compile in Java - every catch block *has* to specify an exception. (And the repetition here is definitely unpleasant...)

Comment: oh yes! I missed this "(Exception excep)" in my code after the catch. And the repetition is upto the owner whether he wants it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the load into a separate method that catches and returns the exception instead of throwing it:

```
private Optional<Exception> tryLoadFromSable(MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject) {
    try {
        marketplaceBOObject.loadFromSable();
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return Optional.of(e);
    }
}
```

Then inside your loop:

```
//inside for loop...
MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject = new MarketplaceBO(entity.getMarketplaceID());
Optional<Exception> loadException = tryLoadFromSable(marketplaceBOObject);
if(loadException.isPresent()) {
    //Do something here, log it, save it in a list for later processing, etc.
}
```

Comment: @Timothy Truckle Nonsense, no different than returning false in this situation

Comment: At least I see a big difference: a (primitive) boolean can never raise an NPE!

Comment: @Timothy Truckle edited to use Optional<Exception> instead of null return value

Comment: I personally don't like `Optional` either but at least its better that the *NULL as error code* variant...

Answer (score 0):

Another "trick" to deal with that is to move the body to the loop into a separate method having the "additional" `try/catch` block:

```
private MarketplaceBO loadFromSable(MerchantMarketplaceBO entity){
    MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject = new MarketplaceBO(entity.getMarketplaceID()); 
    try {          
        marketplaceBOObject.loadFromSable();
     } catch (WhateverException e) {
        // do something to make marketplaceBOObject a valid object
        // or at least log the exception
     }
     return marketplaceBOObject;
}
```

But since we want to stick to the *Same Layer of Abstraction* principle we also need to move other part of that method to new smaller methods:

```
public void serveFromSableV2() {
    String merchantCustomerID = ObfuscatedId.construct(request.getMerchantCustomerID()).getPublicEntityId();
    try {
        List<MerchantMarketplaceBO> merchantMarketplaceBOList =
             getAllMerchantMarketplacesBOsByMerchant();
        Vector<Marketplace> resultVector = new Vector<>();
        for (MerchantMarketplaceBO entity : merchantMarketplaceBOList) {
            MarketplaceBO marketplaceBOObject = loadFromSable(entity);
            addToActiveMarketplacesList(marketplaceBOObject,resultVector);
        }
        verifyHavingActiveMarketPlaces(resultVector);
        setResponseWithWrapped(resultVector);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException | SignatureMismatchException | InvalidIDException e) {
        throw new InvalidIDException("merch=" + merchantCustomerID + "[" + request.getMerchantCustomerID() + "]");    //C++ stack throws InvalidIDException if marketplace is not found in datastore
    }
}
```